# Extract contact info like facebook/google id from contacts list/people app in windows phone

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-8, google-contacts-api

The people app in windows phone keeps all the connected accounts synced. Is there a way to extract this synced information in windows phone(Please note that the user would have authorized my app on Facebook and Google too).

Basically i just need the facebook and google ID or any such identifying credential(of the user's contacts in his contact list) on the phone to maintain a sync across contacts.

I already receive the list of all connected email addresses but I am trying to get the facebook/google userID without having to go through the process of cross referencing them